# Append cart, how do I discount certain items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox cart, what i'm wondering, is it possible to discount certain items with the `append()` function? Like I have an option that upgrades a certain item from basic to advanced and I don't want the discount to apply on that certain item.

*I have a extra question, in the append each item comes with a quantity box, how do I exclude certain items to not have a quantity box and instead just some text?*

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w6ef6mqo/)

```
function buildCart(checked) {
    // This one just builds the sidebar on demand. Quite useful if cart contents can be
    // updated many ways (eg in another tab).
    $("#cart_items").empty();

    $('#total').html('0 €'); //default price for your cart
    var cart_total = 0; //default (because your cart shows 10)


    //For each checked item, add a sidebar element
    for (var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
        //build cart item as appropriate.
        var newItem = $("<div>");
        var checkbox = $("input[name='" + checked[i] + "']");
        $test1 = checkbox.parent('td').siblings('td').html(); // check this, you'll have the item name. (the first td)
        $test2 = checkbox.attr('data-val'); // this will have the value on the "data-val" attribute on your checkbox


        cart_total += parseInt($test2); //add the data-val to the cart_total
        newItem.append('<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="320"><tr> <td width="170" valign="top" align="left"> <div class="product_name">' + $test1 + '</div> </div> </td> <td width="30" valign="top" align="center"> <input type="text" class="quantity" value="1" maxlength="2" /> </td> <td width="70" valign="top" align="center"> <div class="product_total_cost price" data-val="' + $test2 + '">' + $test2 + ' €</div> </td> <td width="9" valign="top" align="right"> <div class="remove_product">X</div> </td> </tr> </table>');

        /*************************/
        var discount_pct = parseInt($(".discount").data("val"), 25);
        var discount = -(cart_total * discount_pct / 100);

        $('.discounted').text('- ' + -discount + ' €');
        $('#total').html(cart_total + discount + " €"); //show this value as the total


        $("#cart_items").append(newItem); 
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="307">
    <tr>
        <td width="190" valign="top" align="left">
            <div class="discount" data-val="10">Discount</div>
        </td>
        <td width="70" valign="top" align="center">
            <div class="discounted" data-val="25">- 0 €</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a data-structure problem.

First, you will need to differentiate the products that qualify for the discount, and the ones that don't. You will also have to differentiate products that can have its quantity edited over the ones that can't.

Currently, all your inputs look like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gold_package" value="Gold package" data-val="40" />
```

I would start by adding a `data-product-type` attribute to set if the product is type "discount" or type "upgrade".

In your script, you will have to push the values of type `discount` onto a different array than type `upgrade`. You can also set items type `upgrade` not to have a quantity box.

Your cart total will then be (`discount[]`*%) + (`upgrade[]`). I hope it helps.